# Segmentation Fault with G++

Tags: c++, string, gdb, g++

I am getting a segmentation error in one part of my program. I've tried a few different methods to get it to work but none have been successful. I debugged it with gdb and got:

> Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
>   0x000000363c49d56e in `std::basic_string <char, std::char_traits <char>, std::allocator <char> >::assign(std::basic_string <char>, std::char_traits <char>,std::allocator                                                       <char> > const&) ()` from /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6

I am not sure what that debugging message means and I did not found anything useful when I searched. Can someone tell me why I am getting this error and how to fix it?

Here is the part of the program with the error.

> ```
>   std::string name, gift, input, token, compare;
>   std::string giant[50], separated[20], individuals[20], items[20];
>   int size, z = 0, x = 0, r =0;
> ```

```
  cout << "****************Opening file to read list.****************" << endl << endl;
  ifstream infile;
  infile.open("input.txt");

  while(!(infile.eof()))
  {
       for(size = 0; size < 20; size++)
       {
             getline(infile, giant[size]);
       }           
       for(z = 0; z < 20; z++) //I believe this loop is the problem.
       {
             std::istringstream identity(giant[z]); 
             while(getline(identity, token, '"'))
             {
                    separated[x] = token;
                    x++;
             }
       }
  }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which learning resource taught you to write `while(!(infile.eof()))` ?

Comment: in which line the core happens? Can you compile with debug information?

Comment: a check over x could be useful inside while(getline(identity, token, '"')) { separated[x] = token; x++;}

Comment: My instructor when we were going over basic file I/O.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about asking other people to debug a code dump.

Comment: @Titan: Be suspicious of what that instructor tells you. "while(!(infile.eof()))" is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value of `x` keeps increasing. You need to do something when `x` reaches 20.

Comment: When `x` has a value of `20` and `separated[20]` is accessed, the buffer overrun occurs.

Answer (score 1):

You're quite clearly going to overrun `separated`.

Use vectors, not arrays, and/or `assert` for the container sizes you expect during your algorithm. Then you will be able to see logic errors much quicker.